# How to find the unknown value(s) in two parallel vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$$\parallel\overrightarrow{a}\parallel =6\text{ and}\parallel\overrightarrow{b}\parallel =3$$

$$2\overrightarrow{a}+(k-3)\overrightarrow{b}\text{ and } k\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\text{ are parallel}$$

Find all the value(s) of k.

How to get the value(s) of k?

I tried the following case,
$$2\overrightarrow{a}+(k-3)\overrightarrow{b}\cdot k\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}=\parallel2\overrightarrow{a}+(k-3)\overrightarrow{b}\parallel\parallel k\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\parallel\cos0$$

$$2\overrightarrow{a}+(k-3)\overrightarrow{b}\cdot k\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}=\parallel2\overrightarrow{a}+(k-3)\overrightarrow{b}\parallel\parallel k\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\parallel\cos\pi$$

but when I reached this point I stopped as I don't know how to continue. Can any one help me?

Comment: Two vectors are parallel whenever their cross product is $0$. Now, the value of $k$ depends on the value of the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

Comment: @Crostul : in fact the value of $k$ is independent from the angle between vectors $a,b$ (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

since the vectors $$\vec{2a}+(k-3)\vec{b}$$ and $$k\vec{a}-\vec{b}$$ are parallel
then exists a real number $t$ with
$$2\vec{a}+(k-3)\vec{b}=t(k\vec{a}-\vec{b})$$ this gives
$$\vec {a}(2-kt)+\vec{b}(k-3+t)=\vec{0}$$
from here we get the System
$$2-kt=0$$
$$k-3+t=0$$
with $$t=\frac{2}{k}$$
plugging this in the second equation we get
$$k-3+\frac{2}{k}=0$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

These vectors are collinear (I wouldn't use the term "parallel") if and only the determinant of their coordinates with respect to basis $\{a,b\}$ is zero:

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}2 & (k-3) \\ k & -1\end{pmatrix}=0 \ \iff \ -2-k(k-3)=0$$

which is an easy-to-solve quadratic equation.

Remark:

a) $\{a,b\}$ is assumed to be a basis.

b) There is no use for the values of their norms.